# Can write to a read-only folder

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis

The environment is Windows 2008 R2, ASP.NET 4, IIS 7. I have a scenario where a user submits some settings to the server, and the server generates a file based on the settings (either a bitmap or an SVG file) and saves the file into a folder.  The image is generated by writing a bitmap and the SVG file is generated by using File.WriteAllText. The user is then redirected to that file.

What I did not expect is that the server was able to create the file without me giving write permissions to the folder. Things I checked:

- w3wp.exe is running under the IIS AppPool/MyUser, the correct app pool identity
- IIS AppPool/MyUser has read permissions to the folder -- if I go to Security/Advanced/Effective Persmissions and check the permissions for MyUser on the folder, I get List Folder/Read Data, Read attributes, Read extended attributes and Read permissions
- If I grab System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name right before the file is written, it's correctly set to the application pool identity.
- The created file's owner is MyUser

What I don't understand is why ASP.NET can create a file in a folder to which the application pool has read-only access?

Comment: Is it possible it grabs the permissions manually and then revokes them later?

Comment: Perhaps it launches a new process with a different user?

Comment: There is literally one line of code after I check for WindowsIdentity: File.WriteAllText(path, builder.ToString()); Besides, the resulting file has the Application Pool identity as its owner, so it appears that the file is created by the app pool, not another user.

Comment: Note that not all directories with read-only access can be written to. For example, there may be hardware limitations.

Comment: Is it _really_ written to _that_ directory? Win7 has a feature called "virtual store" that emulates access to the application home directory by storing the data elsewhere. The application then finds the data in the directory where it's not.

Comment: I mean, I see the file in the folder. There is nothing special about that folder -- it's one of the many folders that's deployed with the web application.

Comment: you see the file - through the web server?

Comment: No, I see it by remoting to the server and using File Explorer to check the file system.

Comment: Can you verify with freeCommander or totalCommander? It could be the file explorer emulates the file presence.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20067/discussion-between-user1044169-and-jan-dvorak)

Comment: sure, let's move to the chat. I'm already there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the Users group had Special permissions of Create File on the folder. Not sure why that is added by default in Windows 2008 -- on all my server boxes, new folders are created with Users having Special permissions of Create Files and some others. The behavior is different on Windows 7 -- no special permissions are added to the Users group.

Anyways, removing that permission addressed the issue.

Thanks.